# Revert and unstage

Tags: git

You can use `git revert --no-commit` to undo changes from a particular change as we all know.  This updates the working copy *and* the index, but does not commit the reversion.  Is there any way to take this a step further and *only* update the working copy without updating the index? (i.e. the changes will be unstanged).  I know you can use `git checkout` to get a working copy of a particular commit, but this also creates a detached head.  I merely want to update the working copy with reverted changes.

Comment: Do you mean `git revert --no-commit`?

Comment: @JB.: `git checkout <commit> -- <path(s)>` will extract old files, but "writes through" the index, staging the changes.  You have to then use `git reset` to un-stage the staged changes.

Comment: @torek Ah, right. Well, what's left? `git cat-file` and a bit of hand-written plumbing? I'm not aware of any command that goes straight from repo to working tree.

Comment: That, or make an extra clone and check out old version, maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a temporary index to leave the original index undisturbed:

```
true_index=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/index
export GIT_INDEX_FILE=.mytmpindex    
cp "$true_index" .mytmpindex
git revert -n  <some-commit-id>
rm .mytmpindex
unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
```

In the case where you have no staged changes that you wish to keep, you can simply do:

```
git revert -n <some-commit-id>
git reset
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the initial `git reset`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: It's to build the new index file but it's probably more quicker and a better match for what you want to just copy the current real index so I've edited it.

Comment: This is cool, but it is more complex/more steps than just doing `git revert -n` followed by `git reset` (with `--soft`, perhaps).  Is there any advantage to this method?

Comment: But `git reset --soft` wouldn't restore your original index and neither would `git reset` as it would reset it to the current `HEAD`. (As you noted, `git revert -n` affects your current index.)

Comment: I understand; this would generally be done with a clean working copy

Comment: @ExplosionPills: By clean working copy do you mean neither staged nor unstaged changes?

Answer (score 2):

If the tree state you want to reach already exists in your history (like, you're reverting the latest commit and absolutely want to do it this way), simply use two resets in a row:

```
wished_index=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
git reset --hard $wished_tree
git reset $wished_index
```

If not, you can still use `revert`, you'll just need to fix your index afterwards:

```
git revert $commit
git reset HEAD^
```

Both ways require a clean working tree (else `git stash` to get there) and leave you with a dirty one.

Comment: This loses uncommitted changes in the original index.

Comment: It does. But OP knows how to use `git stash`.

Comment: But you didn't use git stash? Also, you left out the part where you create the "wished_tree". It's unlikely that there'll already be a tree that represents the revertal of a give commit against the current index.